# while loop to change variable number and check for value

Tags: bash, shell

im new to bash and im trying to figure out the simplest way to create a while loop that changes the variable number, and checks for a value. this way i can simply add to the variables and the if function knows to keep looping to the end

```
var='start loop'
var1='something'
var2='something else'
var3='maybe nothing but probably something'
function run() {
 while [ ! -z "$var" == true ]
 do
  x=1
  var=var$x
  if ! command -v $var &> /dev/null
  then
   DO SOMETHING
  fi
}
x=x+1
done
```

Comment: Use an array to store multiple things: https://linuxhandbook.com/bash-arrays/

Comment: Are you targeting bash or a POSIX shell?

Comment: @Fravadona bash

Comment: `while [ ! -z "$var" == true ]` ?? Surely this gives errors.

Comment: @WilliamPursell yea probably. I am the king of errors. Thank you though. The help was already received and i was able to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

Array was the way. Thank you

```
var=('thing' 'stuff' 'otherStuff')
function run() {
  x=0
  while [ ! -z "${var[x]}" ]
  do
    if ! command -v ${var[x]} &> /dev/null
    then
      apt-get install ${var[x]} -y
    fi
  sleep 2s
  x=$x+1
  done
}
```